# Is there a table of DC motors in relation to weight/mass? I want to find the fastest for my build

Tags: motor, line-following

I am building a line follower robot for a science competition, i have the weight of the components but i don't know what would be the fastest motor i could use to reach the best avg speed of the robot...

Is there some kind of calculator or table of reference for most common dc motors available, weight capacity and avg speed?

Thanks for the attention and sorry if i made the mistake of asking something that was already answered here... i wasn't able to find...

Comment: i mean like fastest "cruise" speed... i'm brazilian, english is not my native language so i might be confusing some times sorry...

Answer (score 2):

I beleive you’re looking for [Power Density](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_density)

How you utilize said power of course is up to your design. You *generally* want the most wattage in the smallest package, and you should get something as to what you’re looking for..but for such a small robot, the speed boost may not be as helpful as being able to accurately and quickly accelerate around/past corners.

Engineering is of course a careful balance between optimal choices. Which is not as trivial as one would think. Good luck on your choice!

Comment: I actually want to know between the "common" dc motors in the market for common uses... ive bought some, some has a good torque but lacks in speed and some have speed but wont be able to accelerate fast and they overheat if the speed keeps varying many times along the track...

Comment: You have to look at the data sheet and compare. Sometimes there are torque vs RPM charts...there isn’t much else to do.

Comment: You can also use gears/gearboxes to trade speed for torque and vise versa